# How do I set the Favicon icon at the top of my website in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I first set it up in the nuxt.config.js file,Then putting the favicon.ico file in the root directory does not work, then putting it in the static folder does not work, and finally putting it in assets does not work, the icon at the top is not displayed

```
head:{
  link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
}
```

I also tried to change the configuration to the following and then adjust it, but it still did not take effect.

```
<head>
  <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
</head>
```

Comment: @esqew I tried all the answers to this question, but it still didn't work.I don't have a 32*32 icon at the moment, I will try this later

Comment: https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/resize-image.php

Comment: @esqew Thank you very much. The 32*32 icon is displayed successfully

Comment: @code Thank you for the tool you provided. My icon is displayed successfully

Comment: @code feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps below to get it done:

1. Navigate to the static folder and delete the favicon.ico file.
2. Now, go ahead and add a new favicon inside the static folder (note that the favicon name should be **favicon.ico**
3. Confirm if your nuxt config file has this in it:

```
link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
```

Comment: This method did not work